# Using Meteor.user() in reactive form field

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to set up an "edit profile" function in Meteor + React. The actual update works fine, but when I load the page, the current data is not displayed. A few console.log() calls reveal that it is initially undefined, probably when the state is set, and a moment later is correctly updated, but then the state has been set already.

For normal subscriptions, I would use $subReady - what do I use for the automatically published user data ?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Card, Loader, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';

// React component
class ProfileCard extends React.Component {
  state = { username: this.props.currentUser ? this.props.currentUser.username : '' }

  handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

  handleSubmit = () => {
    const { username } = this.state
    Meteor.call('user.update', username);
  }

  render() {
    const { username } = this.state
    return (
      <Card fluid>
        { this.props.currentUser ? (
            <Card.Content>
              <Card.Header>Account Data</Card.Header>
              <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <Form.Input
                    label="Username"
                    name="username"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="set user name"
                    value={username}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />

                  <Form.Button primary content="Submit" />
              </Form>
            </Card.Content>
        ) : (
            <Card.Content>
                <Loader />
            </Card.Content>
        )}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker(props => {
  return {
    currentUser: Meteor.user(),
  };
})(ProfileCard);
```

Comment: If `Meteor.user()` is truish then it has been published. There isn't a subscription that you can check the status of. You could simply add `loading: !Meteor.user()`

Comment: I would advice you to use the Meteor.loggingIn() function :
https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loggingIn